# ASP.NET MVC Jasny How to check existing file in edit operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using [Jasny Fileupload](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) to add and update an image to an article.  Everything works fine when the user adds or edits an article, EXCEPT when the user chooses to edit an article with an existing image, but then does not change or remove the image.

Basically my file input is null in this instance, so my code at the moment assumes the user has deleted the image and sets the model property accordingly.

In my controller I have the following:

```
if (file != null)
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/ArticleImages"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    articleToUpdate.ImagePath = fileName;
}
else
{
    articleToUpdate.ImagePath = null;
}
```

My view:

```
@if (Model.article.ImagePath == null)
{
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; margin-top: 10px">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span
                class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file" /></span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-exists" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; margin-top: 10px">
            <img src="/Content/ArticleImages/@Model.article.ImagePath"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span
                class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file" /></span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

How can I, in my contoller, check to see whether the user has not modiied the image, as opposed to  deleting or changing it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your view which exposes a property of your viewmodel indicating the existence of your image.

View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HasImage)
```

ViewModel

```
public bool HasImage
{
    get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ImagePath); }
}
```

Now in your controller

```
if (file != null)
{
    // Save your Image
}
else if (!model.HasImage)
{
    articleToUpdate.ImagePath = null;
}
```

You may need to add a button/javascript to your view so the user can delete and change the value of the hidden field `HasImage`.